# Localization with String from public interface

Tags: java, android, dialog

I've crop library in my app and code to crop Image like this:

```
@Override
public void onPicModeSelected(String mode) {
String action = mode.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PicModes.CAMERA) ? Constants.IntentExtras.ACTION_CAMERA : Constants.IntentExtras.ACTION_GALLERY;
actionProfilePic(action);
}
```

At this time user can see dialog and choose: crop from Gallery or take a photo.
This text (that showes to user) declaired at public class:

```
public class Constants {



public interface IntentExtras {
String ACTION_CAMERA = "action-camera";
String ACTION_GALLERY = "action-gallery";
String IMAGE_PATH = "image-path";
}

public interface PicModes {

String CAMERA = "Сфотографировать"; // THIS TEXT I WANT TO ADD AT LOCALIZATION
String GALLERY = "Выбрать из Галереи";

}
}
```

Now i'm trying to translate my app on english so i want to translate two this Strings. How can i do it?